# Trying to add opacity to a background image with css

Tags: css

Can anyone think why my css doesn't add a transparency color (opacity) overlay on this background image:

```
.header-image {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    /* image must be 1900 x 500 */
    background: url('back.1.jpg') no-repeat center center scroll;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    opacity: 1.0;
}
```

Thanks for all help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my understanding you are not talking about **opacity** in your ***Q*** { *add a transparency colour (opacity) overlay on this background image* }

there are Three methods in my knowledge -

***1#***

```
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.59);
background-image: url('back.1.jpg');
```

***2#*** This is the shorthand and specify it all in one line:

```
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.59) url('back.1.jpg');
```

in the above code `0.59` defines the opacity of the **overlay** colour.

***3#*** this is more of an workaround -

```
.header-image {
  background: url('back.1.jpg') no-repeat center center scroll;
  position:relative;
}
.header-image:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.53);
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

in the above code `background`of `header-image:after`  defines the opacity of the **overlay** colour.

**Rest of your code is ok**

Answer (score -1):

Easy answer is your opacity is set to 1 meaning that it is at full color. If you want to make it more transparent you need to have a value less than 1.

```css
.header-image {
    display: block;
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    /* image must be 1900 x 500 */
    background: url('http://retrotherm.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Intro-Slider-Background-1-500-x-1900.jpg') no-repeat center center scroll;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    opacity: .1;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-image"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just change **opacity** value **1** to less than 1 i.e. 0.3, 0.4 etc.

```
.header-image {
  opacity : 0.3;
}
```